# boolean value converting into integer by Hibernate with postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am new in this when I am trying to insert boolean value into postgres database but   hibernate convert boolean value into int value 0 or 1. But I have to store only boolean value please help me Thanks in Advance.

```
, activityDate=2014-05-02, venue=fvfg, noOfParticipants=34, outcome='', notes=df, isComplete=false, misAuditBean=MISAuditBean [entBy=0, entDate=2014-05-02 10:36:58.557, authBy=0, authDate=nu
ll, freezedBy=0, freezedDate=null, status=U], iecActivityMaterialUtilizationBeans=null,expenditure=0.01]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [insert into prwss_main.t_ccdu_iec_progress (activity_date, block_id, expenditure, activity_
id, is_complete, location_id, auth_by, auth_date, ent_by, ent_date, freeze_by, freeze_date, status, no_of_participants, notes, outcome, venue, village_id, iec_progress_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?
, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:637)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy37.saveCBIECActivityProgress(Unknown Source)
        at com.prwss.mis.ccdu.iecactivity.struts.IecActivityProgressAction.save(IecActivityProgressAction.java:209)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
        at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:113)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into prwss_main.t_ccdu_iec_progress (activity_date, block_id, expenditure, activity_id, is_complete, location_id, auth_by, auth
_date, ent_by, ent_date, freeze_by, freeze_date, status, no_of_participants, notes, outcome, venue, village_id, iec_progress_id) values (2014-05-02 -07:00:00, D09B02, 0.01, ACT18, 0, DIV27,
0, NULL, 0, 2014-05-02 10:36:58.557000 -07:00:00, 0, NULL, U, 34, df, '', fvfg, 16983, 16802) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2545)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1344)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:344)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2682)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
```

Comment: What versions of PostgreSQL and Hibernate are you using?

Comment: Hi Steve Sorry for delay in reply. I am using PostgreSQL 9.1 and Hibernate 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ability to translate boolean values to SQL boolean types was added to Hibernate 3.1.

Looks like it was possibly a consequence of [HHH-477 Boolean discriminators generate invalid SQL for PostgreSQL dialect](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-477).